# C#/Entity Framework Method to Return List of Classes Throwing Constructor Error

Tags: c#, list, generics, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a generic Entity Framework class that I can use to get typed lists.   I'm modeling it after this:   [How can I use Activator.CreateInstance to create a List<T> where T is unknown at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284671/how-can-i-use-activator-createinstance-to-create-a-listt-where-t-is-unknown-at)

The problem I'm having is that my type -  targetType.GetInterfaces()  - doesn't return any interfaces.   When I try to add items, I get a constructor error.

list.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(targetType,obj)));   Throws Constructor on Type myType Not Found

Here is the usage:

```
List<myType> myVariable = new List<myType>();
myVariable = ListTableContents((dynamic)(new myType()).GetType());

public static IList ListTableContents(Type targetType  )
    {
        
        using (var db = new myContext())
        {
           
            var method = typeof(DbContext).GetMethod("Set").MakeGenericMethod(targetType);
            var query = method.Invoke(db, null) as IQueryable;
            // This works - I have a list of objects  
            List<object> retObj = query.OfType<object>().ToList();

             
            Type iListType = typeof(IList);

            if (!targetType.GetInterfaces().Contains(iListType))
            {
               // hits this every time 
                throw new ArgumentException("No IList", nameof(targetType));
            }

            Type elementType = targetType.GenericTypeArguments.FirstOrDefault();
            IList list = Activator.CreateInstance(targetType) as IList;
        
              
            foreach (var obj in retObj)
            {
               //   Constructor Not Found
                list.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(targetType, obj));
            }

            
            return  list; 
        }
         
    }
```

Here is the class constructor.   As you can see, it's Entity Framework:

```
public partial class myType
{
    public myType()
    {
        myTypes = new HashSet<myType>();
    }

    public string myTypeStringType { get; set; } 
    public int myTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<myType> myTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your `targetType` have a constructor that takes in an `object`?

Comment: In the post you linked, the check for `IList` is on a *collection*, which is an `IList` - you're checking on `myType`, which is likely not an `IList`. Change the calling code: `myVariable = ListTableContents(typeof(List<myType>)); `. Also, please post code for `myType` - it appears you're asking 2 questions here. We can  presume  `myType` is constructable as shown - that is, it has an accessible `myType(object)` constructor; however, this point should be clarified in your question, and the question should really focus on a single problem.

Comment: @JohanP - It doesn't contain a constructor that takes and object.  It's Entity Framework and I was trying to create generic code that I could use any time I needed to populate a full list with the full table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't have a class constructor that took an object.  I solved it by adding a dynamic cast method.

Usage:

List myList =  ListTableContents((dynamic)(new myType()).GetType());

Methods:

```
    //   This returns the entire table as a list of classes
    public static IList ListTableContents(Type targetType)
    {

        using (var db = new myContext())
        {
            var method = typeof(DbContext).GetMethod("Set").MakeGenericMethod(targetType);
            var query = method.Invoke(db, null) as IQueryable;
            List<object> retObj = query.OfType<object>().ToList();

            // Create a list of the required type and cast to IList
            Type genericListType = typeof(List<>);
            Type concreteListType = genericListType.MakeGenericType(targetType);
            IList list = Activator.CreateInstance(concreteListType) as IList;  
          
            // Add values
            foreach (var obj in retObj)
            { 
                list.Add(Cast(obj, targetType));
            }

            return list;
             
        }

    }
    public static dynamic Cast(dynamic obj, Type castTo)
    {
        return Convert.ChangeType(obj, castTo);
    }
```